# How to get first unoccupied rows from Excel file using c#.net?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am on a winform application which performs operations with excel files.

Now i have got an issue that i need to get first unused rows occured before a used row(edited row).

I have used the below code and which gives only the usedrange.

```
        string fileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"\\123.xlsx";
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlApp.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1];
        Excel.Range excelCell = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        Object[,] values = (Object[,])excelCell.Value2;
        int rows = values.GetLength(0);
        int cols = values.GetLength(1);
```

**Exmlple:**

[image]

From the above example i need to get the result as '3' Cols and '10' rows.

Now its '3'Cols and '7'rows.

Please help me if there is any idea for this. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty - you could use something like the following:

```
int rows = excelCell.Rows.Count + excelCell.Row - 1;
```

And something similar for columns.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I could use **excelCell.Row**  property.Its now fine.